# Finding the maximum value per column in each sub-list in python

Tags: python, list

I'm just wondering how to do the `max()` and `min()` when it is a 2 dimensional array. I searched everywhere and I do manage to find something but it is not printing in the corresponding column.

Code:

```
import random
students = int(input("How many students do you want to enter? \n Students: "))

Student_Count =  [([0] * 4) for i in range(students)]
for a in range(students):
    for b in range(4):
        Student_Count[a][b] = random.randint(1,100)
Max = (list(map(max,Student_Count)))
Min = (list(map(min,Student_Count)))

for a in range (students):
    print("Student", a + 1 , end = "\t\t\t")
    for b in range (4):
        print(Student_Count[a][b], end = "\t\t\t ") # the print of Random numbers
    print()
print("_____________________________________________________________")
print("Highest", end = "\t\t\t\t")
for c in range (4):
    print(Max[c], end = "\t\t\t ")
print()
print("Lowest", end = "\t\t\t\t ")
for c in range (4):
    print(Min[c], end = "\t\t\t ")
```

output:

```
How many students do you want to enter? 
 Students: 5
Student 1                       84                       84                      49                      48                    
Student 2                       47                       28                      81                      81                    
Student 3                       89                       31                      95                      79                    
Student 4                       21                       16                      21                      94                    
Student 5                       87                       51                      63                      14                    
_____________________________________________________________
Highest                         84                       81                      95                      94                    
Lowest                           48                      28                      31                      16
```

EDIT: Sorry for the ambiguous question

My expected outcome for the code is to get the maximum and the minimum value of each column in the list

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: what will be your expected output ?

Comment: The code does work as expected. It prints out the highest and the lowest score per student

Comment: The student scores have a student per line, and the high/low have a student per column

Comment: I have run your code i am uploading it with some changes, then check it is as your expected output ?

Comment: umm my expected output is to get the lowest and the highest value in each column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're aiming for is the minimum of each position, I think the easiest thing is to pull out a sequence of those values and apply min/max to those:

```
import random

student_count = [
    [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(4)]
    for _ in range(int(input(
        "How many students do you want to enter? \nStudents: "
    )))
]

maxima = [max(student[i] for student in student_count) for i in range(4)]
minima = [min(student[i] for student in student_count) for i in range(4)]
sep = "\t"

for a, student in enumerate(student_count):
    print(f"Student {a+1}{sep}{sep.join(map(str, student))}")

print("_____________________________________________________________")
print(f"Highest\t{sep}{sep.join(map(str, maxima))}")
print()
print(f"Lowest\t{sep}{sep.join(map(str, minima))}")
```

```
How many students do you want to enter?
Students: 9
Student 1       95      48      19      14
Student 2       37      79      62      93
Student 3       29      73      79      11
Student 4       76      18      9       88
Student 5       39      57      5       4
Student 6       42      92      6       31
Student 7       69      39      70      61
Student 8       16      89      33      76
Student 9       65      54      12      62
_____________________________________________________________
Highest         95      92      79      93

Lowest          16      18      5       4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
students = int(input("How many students do you want to enter? \n Students: "))

Student_Count =  [([0] * 4) for i in range(students)]
for a in range(students):
    for b in range(4):
        Student_Count[a][b] = random.randint(1,100)
Max = (list(map(max,Student_Count)))
Min = (list(map(min,Student_Count)))
print(Max)
print(Min)

for a in range(students):
    print("Student", a + 1 , end = "\t\t\t")
    for b in range (4):
        print(Student_Count[a][b], end = "\t\t\t ") # the print of Random numbers
    print()
print("_____________________________________________________________")
print("Highest", end = "\t\t\t\t")
for c in range(students):
    print(Max[c], end = "\t\t\t ")
print()
print("Lowest", end = "\t\t\t\t ")
for c in range(students):
    print(Min[c], end = "\t\t\t ")
```

**Output:**
[image: This is output]

Comment: @TenebrisMortem let me know in comments, Is this your expected output?

Comment: ummmm the expected output for the highest should be [100,94,87] and the lowest should be [79,69,5]

Comment: student 1 highest is 100 student 2 highest is 94 student 3 highest is also 94

Comment: student 1 lowest is 14 student 2 lowest is 2 student 3 lowest is 20.

Comment: if your code is finding the minimum and maximum marks per student, then your code working fine.